# Recharge electronic cigarette battery

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

My electronic cigarette broke the power button but the battery is still new. I have another one that has the button working.

The battery is like the one in the picture below, and I wonder if I can recharge on an ordinary 3v battery charger.

These batteries are standard, it only says 3.7 Wh, by Joyetech. Usually these batteries are charged to the **USB** port of the PC

Comment: `I have another one that has the button working.` is there any reason why you mentioned that?

Comment: the picture of the battery is useless because the label on the battery is covered

Comment: @PapaCharlie Maybe... take a picture... of the one you got in real life? Or do you want me to copy and paste some random answer on internet?

Comment: @PapaCharlie Okay, do it your way. Not something I recommend. - Either way, you still haven't told us the voltage which is the most important part. - What you've asked is what you should fuel your car with. And you're telling us "*It has 3.7 Horse powers*". And then you copy and paste an image of some Volvo from the Internet. The answer could be 95 octane, 98 octane... maybe diesel.. maybe biogas... who knows.

Comment: photo looks like a fake battery with fake specs 70Wh hahaha

Comment: The one in your picture says "70Wh".

Answer (score 1):

it is unknown what kind of a battery you have

so the answer is NO, you cannot recharge on an ordinary 3v battery charger.